# how to initialise NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have a loop which adds values to an `NSMutableArray`, however when I move on to the next batch I need to clear down and initialise the array to add the next lot of data and I thought using `[jobList release]` would do the trick but it doesn't. Could someone please let me know what I can use to reset the array after each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send `-release` to it, then it is *likely, but **not certain*** that the object will be deallocated and not *cleared* as you want it to be.

The solution is super-simple: Use the [`-removeAllObjects`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABBEADI) method:

```
for(id x in jobList) {
  //...
}

[jobList removeAllObjects];

//...
```

Comment: +1 but it's worse than that even. It's likely *but not certain* that it will be deallocated. Sometimes it won't be, and you can use it in blissful ignorance of its transient nature until boom.

Comment: Thank you that worked fine. However, what happens now is that each key group is overwritten by the last key group. So that if the first starts with 10 items and then I clear the array. When I add the next group which has 12 items, the first group suddenly has the same 12 items also. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a`release`may cause the object to be deallocated if no other objects retain it, so you definitely don't want to do that.

To do a clear down use`removeAllObjects`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `[jobList removeAllObjects];`

Answer (score 0):

Using `release` will deallocate the object which you are accessing, and this is wrong. I think you are looking for

```
[jobList removeAllObjects];
```